# Powershell Script not outputting data into File outside of ISE

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I understand that other people have had similar questions but none are like this. I made a ps1 script to convert an a file of XML objects into a CSV file of rows representing some of that data. Last night I was able to run the batch file and convert files, but this morning it saves an empty CSV file when I run from batch but it works fine when I run it in Powershell ISE.

I run it from a batch file with -STA mode to enable it to open the dialog windows:

```
powershell -sta C:\Users\*******\Downloads\JiraXMLtoCSV.ps1
```

And here is the script(it was tough to make this code block lol excuse the '}'):

```
    # This function will open a file-picker for the user to select their Jira XML Export
    Function Get-JiraXMLFile(){ 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null;
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location;
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null;
$OpenFileDialog.filename;
$OpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true;
}

    # This function will open the file save dialong to allow the user to choose location and name of the converted XML-to-CSV file
    Function Get-SaveFile(){ 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null;

$SaveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog;
$SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location;
$SaveFileDialog.filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
$SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null;
$SaveFileDialog.filename;
$SaveFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true;
} 




    # Invoke the file-picker function and obtain input file 
    $inputFile = Get-JiraXMLFile;

    #initialize list for items that will be extracted from XML Input File
    $list = @(); 

    # Loop through all the items in Jira XML export file
    foreach ( $item in $XMLFile.rss.channel.item ) {

# Create a new hash object
$issue = @{}; 

# Gather wanted attributes
$issue.Key = $item.key.InnerXML;
$issue.StatusColor = $item.statusCategory.colorName;
$issue.Status = $item.status.InnerXML;

# Check for comments 
if ( $item.comments ) {
    # Record the comments with column name/header format as follows: comment #0 | comment #2|...
    # Change this value to 1 if you want to see it start at comment #1 instead of comment #0
    $incrementalCounter = 0;
    # Loop through all comments on the issue
    foreach ( $comment in $item.comments.comment ) {
        $issue.("comment #"+$incrementalCounter) = $comment.InnerXML;
        $incrementalCounter += 1;
    }

}
#Create an object to be added to the list
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $issue;
Write-Output $object;

# add this issue to the list to convert/export to CSV
$list += $object;
```

}

```
# Open File Saving window to choose file name and location for the new
$OutputFile = Get-SaveFile;
$list | Export-Csv -Path ($OutputFile) -NoTypeInformation;
```

And if you want some sample XML to help me learn what I am doing wrong:

```
    <rss version="0.92">
    <channel>
    <title>XML Export</title>
    <link>...</link>
    <description>An XML representation of a search request</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <issue start="0" end="7" total="7"/>
    <build-info>...</build-info>
    <item>
    <title>[AJT-46] another new story</title>
    <project id="1652" key="AJT">Advanced Training</project>
    <description/>
    <environment/>
    <key id="220774">AJT-46</key>     
    <status id="16615" iconUrl="https://website.com/" description="Desc text">To Do</status>
    <statusCategory id="2" key="new" colorName="gray"/>
    <labels></labels>
    <created>Tue, 5 Jun 2018 11:25:38 -0400</created>
    <updated>Tue, 5 Jun 2018 11:29:00 -0400</updated>
    <due/>
    </item>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

It was working last night and now it is not working when I showed up this morning so nothing changed that I know of, I didn't reboot either. It still works in the Powershell ISE which is fine but I need the batch file method for the person I am making it for. Any help, advice, etc. is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Not much of a batch guy, so please bear with me...Are you using any Powershell-specific cmdlets that might make vanilla batch mad? Also, you're using objects here. Isn't regular cmd batch like only text-based...?

Comment: Most likely you have something in memory in your ISE session. Having said that, I don't see anywhere that Get-SaveFile returns a value.

Comment: Maybe it simply has to do with **ExecutionPolicy**.. If you run it in de ISE it works, but running from the batch file as a different user, this user may not have permissions to do so.
You could try `powershell -sta -File "C:\Users\*******\Downloads\JiraXMLtoCSV.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

p.s. I double quoted the path to the file because if there is a space in there the batch file would not know where to find it. Also
if the machine has Powershell version is 3.0 or higher, you do not need to specify the -Sta switch because it is the default for 3.0 and up.

Comment: I kept trying and found out that it is a Batch side problem. Now it isn't accepting the Powershell System.Xml so it must just hate XML. I'm not sure what to do anymore. Is there a better way to run a powershell 2 script in STA mode from a separate file? Separate because apparently the script can run itself in STA mode

Comment: I casted this `# Invoke the file-picker function and obtain input file 
[Xml]$inputFile = Get-JiraXMLFile;`, and then did this `
    $items = Select-Xml "//rss/channel/item" -Xml $inputFile;` and then had to access $items.Node to get the values. Not sure what I'm doing but I hope this helps someone one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes I made and it works now, double newline separated:

```
# Invoke the file-picker function and obtain input file 
[Xml]$inputFile = Get-JiraXMLFile;


# Grab all the items we exported, ignore the header info
if ( $inputFile ) {
    #$XmlComments = Select-Xml "//comment()" -Xml $inputFile;
    #$inputFile.RemoveChild($XmlComments);
    $items = Select-Xml "//rss/channel/item" -Xml $inputFile;
}


# Iterate over items and grab important info to be put into CSV format
foreach ( $item in $items ){
# Create a new hash object
$issue = @{}; 


# Gather wanted attributes
if( $item.Node.key){
    $issue.Key = $item.Node.key.InnerXML;
}
```